# In an F# signature file, what is the significance of parentheses around a function signature?

Tags: f#

As the consumer of an .fsi signature file what difference, if any, is there between:

```
val sum : int -> int -> int
```

and

```
val sum : (int -> int -> int)
```

It seems that the second can be implemented by a function definition *or* by a function 'alias', but the first can only be implemented by a function definition.

With the following:

```
// .fsi
val add : int -> int -> int
val sum : int -> int -> int
```

```
// .fs
let add a b = a + b
let sum = add
```

an error is generated

```
error FS0034: Module 'Butter' contains
    val sum : (int -> int -> int)
but its signature specifies
    val sum : int -> int -> int
```

however if the signature file is:

```
// .fsi
val add : (int -> int -> int)
val sum : (int -> int -> int)
```

it compiles ok.

Is this behaviour intentional, and if so how are the parentheses changing the interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is intentional behaviour.

In creating a simpler example in response to Tom's answer I actually read the error message properly it says:

> The arities in the signature and implementation differ. The signature
> specifies that 'sum' is function definition or lambda expression
> accepting at least 2 argument(s), but the implementation is a computed
> function value. To declare that a computed function value is a permitted
> implementation simply parenthesize its type in the signature, e.g.↔ val
> sum: int -> (int -> int)↔instead of↔ val sum: int -> int -> int.

So the parenthesis are used to indicated a computed expression is an allowed implementation as well lambdas and function definitions. (I won't pretend I properly understand the difference.)

Answer (score 0):

What's Tuple here? If it's .NET's `System.Tuple`, then this doesn't make sense.

```
val x : Tuple -> float
```

Would be a function that takes the *static class* Tuple and returns a float. If you want a tuple instance, then you'll need to specify exactly which n-tuple type you want (`Tuple<'a>` and `Tuple<'a, 'b>` are two different types).

The following should work:

```
var x : Tuple<float, _, _, _> -> float
```

Comment: Thank you Tom.  My inclusion of `Tuple` in the example makes it unnecessarily confusing  This Tuple is a domain type not related to the language's Tuples.  But to double check this isn't the issue, and to reduce confusion I've recreated the issue with much simpler code.  I will update my question and I plan to upload some demo code too. (The original code is for 'The Ray Tracer Challenge'.) Thanks.